# How do I group the results by month?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, union

Currently, my codes here produces such results:

```
 SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS  MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM news
 GROUP BY MONTH 

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS MONTH , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM equipment
 GROUP BY MONTH 

 RESULTS:
 YEAR MONTH TOTAL
 2013 FEB    1 (news table)
 2013 JAN   12 (news table)
 2013 FEB    1 (equipment table)
 2013 JAN   11 (equipment table)
```

How do I edit the SQL query such that I will be able to only show:

> ```
>  RESULTS:
>  YEAR MONTH TOTAL
>  2013 FEB    2 (both news and equipment table)
>  2013 JAN   23 (both news and equipment table)
> ```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Put the whole thing in an outer 'select' and do your grouping and counting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT YEAR, MONTH, SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
FROM (SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS  MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM news
 GROUP BY MONTH 

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS MONTH , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM equipment
 GROUP BY MONTH) x
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Select year, month, sum(total) from
(
SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS  MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM news
 GROUP BY MONTH 

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS MONTH , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM equipment
 GROUP BY MONTH 
)
group by year, month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR, MONTH, SUM(total) total 
FROM (SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
      FROM news 
      GROUP BY MONTH
      UNION ALL
      SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS MONTH , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
      FROM equipment 
      GROUP BY MONTH
     ) AS A 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.year, x.month, sum(x.total) from x(
 SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS  MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM news
 GROUP BY MONTH 

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT YEAR(date_added) AS YEAR, MONTHNAME(date_added) AS MONTH , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
 FROM equipment
 GROUP BY MONTH ) x
group by x.month, x.year
```